# Sorting n-tuples

Tags: sorting

I've just hashed up the following hair-brained idea of how to sort n-tuples of integers, as demonstrated below with a set of 3-tuples:

```
[ 4 , 1 , 3 ]
[ 1 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 3 ]
[ 1 , 2 , 2 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 3 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 4 ]
```

First "partition" data by 1st index, thusly (as shown by the dotted lines)

```
[ 1 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 2 , 2 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 3 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 1 ]
......................
[ 2 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 2 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 1 ]
......................
[ 3 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 4 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 3 ]
......................
[ 4 , 1 , 3 ]
```

Further next, I "partition" the previous partitions by the 2nd index

```
[ 1 , 1 , 3 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 1 ]
.....................
[ 1 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 2 , 2 ]
......................
[ 2 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 1 ]
......................
[ 2 , 2 , 1 ]
......................
[ 3 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 4 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 3 ]
......................
[ 4 , 1 , 3 ]
```

Finally I partition by 3rd index

```
[ 1 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 3 ]
.....................
[ 1 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 2 , 2 ]
......................
[ 2 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 2 ]
......................
[ 2 , 2 , 1 ]
......................
[ 3 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 3 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 4 ]
......................
[ 4 , 1 , 3 ]
```

This seems to have the potential of being cache-friendly. Is it a sensible algorithm (or totally stupid) or have I reinvented the wheel here?

Comment: It's not particularly cache-friendly, as it does a separate pass for each radix.  If the tuples/strings have long distinguishing prefixes, it thrashes.

Comment: @KWillets I though it did considering that the partitions get smaller, enough to fit a cache.

Comment: They don't always get smaller.

Comment: Your description of the algorithm is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've rediscovered [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: I've been doing a bit more research, isn't it closer to postman's sort?
http://www.rrsd.com/software_development/postmans_sort/cuj/cuj.htm

Comment: @Olumide Postman's sort *is* a radix sort. It says as much on the Radix Sort Wikipedia page. On the Bucket Sort Wikipedia page which covers Postman's sort, it incorrectly suggests that radix sort is constrained to a number of buckets that is a power of two. In the metaphor used by radix sort, postman's sort is a most significant digit first radix sort where the key is represented as a number in a potentially [mixed radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) number system.

Comment: @DerekElkins I agree. But the postman's sort has a hierarchical component which I'm not certain radix sort prescribes.

Comment: I don't see a Radix Sort here. Integers are "unbounded" and I see no mention of any bucket.

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us how you perform the "partitions", and in particular how you perform the sorts on the respective tuple elements. So it is hard to say if your rediscovered a radix-sort-like procedure or just successive sorting passes.

By the way, it is probably more efficient to use a standard sort with a lexicographical comparison function (compare the first components, and in case of equality compare the second, and so on), as the number of moves can be lower and some comparisons are spared.